# Polynomial Class in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented

This was one of my friends' Java OOP class assignments. They were tasked with writing a polynomial class in Java with multiplication functionality. I did it in C++ as a challenge and for improving my programming skills. I also added a little bit of extra functionality.

## Header File

***polynomial.hpp***

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class polynomial
{
public:
    char var = 'x';

    polynomial();
    polynomial(const std::string&, const char variable);
    polynomial(const std::string&);
    // construction by coefficients
    polynomial(const std::vector<long double>&);

    const std::size_t order() const;
    long double &operator[](const std::size_t&);
    const long double &operator[](const std::size_t&) const;
    long double &coefficient(const std::size_t&);
    const long double &coefficient(const std::size_t&) const;
    polynomial &operator=(const std::string&);

    // adds the argument to this polynomial
    void add(const polynomial&);
    // returns this polynomial + the argument
    polynomial plus(const polynomial&) const;
    polynomial operator+(const polynomial&) const;
    polynomial &operator+=(const polynomial&);

    // subtract the argument from this polynomial
    void subtract(const polynomial&);
    // returns this polynomial - the argument
    polynomial minus(const polynomial&) const;
    polynomial operator-(const polynomial&) const;
    polynomial &operator-=(const polynomial&);

    // multiplies this polynomial by the argument
    void multiply(const polynomial&);
    // returns this polynomial * the argument
    polynomial times(const polynomial&) const;
    polynomial operator*(const polynomial&) const;
    polynomial &operator*=(const polynomial&);

    bool operator==(const polynomial&) const;
    void print(std::ostream&) const;
    void print(std::ostream&, const char variable) const;

private:
    std::vector<long double> coefficients;
};

polynomial add(const polynomial&, const polynomial&);
polynomial subtract(const polynomial&, const polynomial&);
polynomial multiply(const polynomial&, const polynomial&);

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const polynomial&);
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream&, polynomial&);
```

## Source File

***polynomial.cpp***

```
#include "polynomial.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

polynomial::polynomial()
{
    coefficients.push_back(0);
}

bool isNumber(const char);
long double parseNumber(const std::string &in, std::size_t &index, const bool negative_flag);
void setExponent(unsigned &exponent, const char variable,
                 const std::string &poly, std::size_t &index);
void addCoefficient(long double &num, unsigned &exponent, std::vector<long double>& coefficients);

polynomial::polynomial(const std::string &poly, const char variable)
: var{variable}
{
    long double num;
    unsigned exponent;
    bool negative_flag = false;
    coefficients.push_back(0);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < poly.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (isNumber(poly[i]))
        {
            num = parseNumber(poly, i, negative_flag);
            setExponent(exponent, var, poly, i);
            addCoefficient(num, exponent, coefficients);
        }
        else if (poly[i] == var)
        {
            num = 1;
            if (negative_flag)
                num *= -1;
            --i;
            setExponent(exponent, var, poly, i);
            addCoefficient(num, exponent, coefficients);
        }
        else if (poly[i] == '-')
            negative_flag = true;
        else if (poly[i] == '+')
            negative_flag = false;
    }
}

polynomial::polynomial(const std::string &poly)
: polynomial(poly, 'x') {}

bool isNumber(const char character)
{
    return (character >= '0' && character <= '9') || character == '.';
}

long double parseNumber(const std::string &poly, std::size_t &index, const bool negative_flag)
{
    long double number;
    std::string num_string;
    num_string.push_back(poly[index]);
    while (index + 1 < poly.length() && isNumber(poly[index + 1]))
    {
        ++index;
        num_string.push_back(poly[index]);
    }

    std::stringstream numstream;
    numstream << num_string;
    numstream >> number;
    if (negative_flag)
        number *= -1;
    return number;
}

void setExponent(unsigned &exponent, const char variable,
                 const std::string &poly, std::size_t &index)
{
    if (index + 1 < poly.size() && poly[index + 1] == variable)
    {
        ++index;
        if (index + 1 < poly.size() && poly[index + 1] == '^')
        {
            index += 2;
            exponent = parseNumber(poly, index, false);
        }
        else
            exponent = 1;
    }
    else
        exponent = 0;
}

void addCoefficient(long double &num, unsigned &exponent, std::vector<long double>& coefficients)
{
    if (exponent + 1 > coefficients.size())
        coefficients.resize(exponent + 1, 0);
    coefficients[exponent] += num;
}

polynomial::polynomial(const std::vector<long double>& poly)
: coefficients{poly} {}

const std::size_t polynomial::order() const
{
    return coefficients.size() - 1;
}

long double &polynomial::operator[](const std::size_t &index)
{
    return coefficients[index];
}

const long double &polynomial::operator[](const std::size_t &index) const
{
    return coefficients[index];
}

long double &polynomial::coefficient(const std::size_t &index)
{
    return coefficients[index];
}

const long double &polynomial::coefficient(const std::size_t &index) const
{
    return coefficients[index];
}

polynomial &polynomial::operator=(const std::string &poly)
{
    *this = polynomial(poly);
    return *this;
}

void polynomial::add(const polynomial &poly)
{
    if (poly.order() > this->order())
        coefficients.resize(poly.order() + 1, 0);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= poly.order(); ++i)
        coefficients[i] += poly[i];
    // removing extra zeros
    for (size_t i = coefficients.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (coefficients[i] != 0)
            break;
        else
            coefficients.pop_back();
    }
}

polynomial polynomial::plus(const polynomial &poly) const
{
    std::vector<long double> res = coefficients;
    if (poly.order() > this->order())
        res.resize(poly.order() + 1, 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= poly.order(); ++i)
        res[i] += poly[i];
    // removing extra zeros
    for (size_t i = res.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (res[i] != 0)
            break;
        else
            res.pop_back();
    }
    return polynomial(res);
}

polynomial polynomial::operator+(const polynomial &poly) const
{
    return this->plus(poly);
}

polynomial &polynomial::operator+=(const polynomial &poly)
{
    this->add(poly);
    return *this;
}

void polynomial::subtract(const polynomial &poly)
{
    if (poly.order() > this->order())
        coefficients.resize(poly.order() + 1, 0);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= poly.order(); ++i)
        coefficients[i] -= poly[i];
    // removing extra zeros
    for (size_t i = coefficients.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (coefficients[i] != 0)
            break;
        else
            coefficients.pop_back();
    }
}

polynomial polynomial::minus(const polynomial &poly) const
{
    std::vector<long double> res = coefficients;
    if (poly.order() > this->order())
        res.resize(poly.order() + 1, 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= poly.order(); ++i)
        res[i] -= poly[i];
    // removing extra zeros
    for (size_t i = res.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (res[i] != 0)
            break;
        else
            res.pop_back();
    }
    return polynomial(res);
}

polynomial polynomial::operator-(const polynomial &poly) const
{
    return this->minus(poly);
}

polynomial &polynomial::operator-=(const polynomial &poly)
{
    this->subtract(poly);
    return *this;
}

void polynomial::multiply(const polynomial &poly)
{
    std::vector<long double> res(this->order() + poly.order() + 1, 0);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= this->order(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j <= poly.order(); ++j)
            res[i + j] += coefficients[i] * poly[j];
    coefficients = res;
}

polynomial polynomial::times(const polynomial &poly) const
{
    std::vector<long double> res(this->order() + poly.order() + 1, 0);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= this->order(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j <= poly.order(); ++j)
            res[i + j] += coefficients[i] * poly[j];
    return polynomial(res);
}

polynomial polynomial::operator*(const polynomial &poly) const
{
    return this->times(poly);
}

polynomial &polynomial::operator*=(const polynomial &poly)
{
    this->multiply(poly);
    return *this;
}

polynomial add(const polynomial &poly1, const polynomial &poly2)
{
    return poly1.plus(poly2);
}

polynomial subtract(const polynomial &poly1, const polynomial &poly2)
{
    return poly1.minus(poly2);
}

polynomial multiply(const polynomial &poly1, const polynomial &poly2)
{
    return poly1.times(poly2);
}

bool polynomial::operator==(const polynomial& poly) const
{
    if (this->order() != poly.order())
        return false;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= this->order(); ++i)
        if (coefficients[i] != poly[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

void polynomial::print(std::ostream &out) const
{
    print(out, var);
}

void polynomial::print(std::ostream &out, const char variable) const
{
    std::size_t exponent = this->order() + 1;
    while (exponent > 0)
    {
        --exponent;
        long double num = coefficients[exponent];
        if (num != 0)
        {
            if (num < 0)
            {
                num *= -1;
                out << "- ";
            }
            else if (exponent != this->order())
                out << "+ ";

            out << num;
            if (exponent > 0)
            {
                out << variable;
                if (exponent > 1)
                    out << '^' << exponent;
            }
            out << ' ';
        }
    }
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const polynomial &poly)
{
    poly.print(out);
    return out;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, polynomial &poly)
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(in >> std::ws, input);
    poly = input;
    return in;
}
```

## Unit tests

```
void TestPolynomialConstructor()
{
    assert(polynomial("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2") == polynomial("4x^2 + 2x + 1"));
}

void TestPolynomialConstructor_void()
{
    polynomial poly("0"), poly_void;
    assert(poly == poly_void);
}

void TestPolynomialConstructor_var()
{
    polynomial poly1("3t + 1 - t + 4t^2", 't'), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    poly2.var = 't';
    assert(poly1 == poly2);
}

void TestPolynomialOrder()
{
    polynomial poly("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2");
    assert(poly.order() == 3);
}

void TestPolynomialCoefficient()
{
    polynomial poly("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(poly.coefficient(1) == 2);
}

void TestPolynomialCoefficient_operator()
{
    polynomial poly("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(poly[1] == 2);
}

void TestPolynomialAddition_plus()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(poly1.plus(poly2) == polynomial("6x^3 + 14x^2 + 2x + 6"));
}

void TestPolynomialAddition_operator()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(poly1 + poly2 == polynomial("6x^3 + 14x^2 + 2x + 6"));
}

void TestPolynomialAddition_addtothis()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    poly1.add(poly2);
    assert(poly1 == polynomial("6x^3 + 14x^2 + 2x + 6"));
}

void TestPolynomialAddition_addtothis_operator()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    poly1 += poly2;
    assert(poly1 == polynomial("6x^3 + 14x^2 + 2x + 6"));
}

void TestPolynomialAddition_function()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(add(poly1, poly2) == polynomial("6x^3 + 14x^2 + 2x + 6"));
}

void TestPolynomialSubtraction_minus()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("6x^3 + 3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(poly1.minus(poly2) == polynomial("6x^2 - 2x + 4"));
}

void TestPolynomialSubtraction_operator()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("6x^3 + 3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(poly1 - poly2 == polynomial("6x^2 - 2x + 4"));
}

void TestPolynomialSubtraction_subtractfromthis()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("6x^3 + 3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    poly1.subtract(poly2);
    assert(poly1 == polynomial("6x^2 - 2x + 4"));
}

void TestPolynomialSubtraction_subtractfromthis_operator()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("6x^3 + 3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    poly1 -= poly2;
    assert(poly1 == polynomial("6x^2 - 2x + 4"));
}

void TestPolynomialSubtraction_function()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("6x^3 + 3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(subtract(poly1, poly2) == polynomial("6x^2 - 2x + 4"));
}

void TestPolynomialMultiplication_times()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(poly1.times(poly2) == polynomial("24x^5 + 52x^4 + 26x^3 + 30x^2 + 10x + 5"));
}

void TestPolynomialMultiplication_operator()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(poly1 * poly2 == polynomial("24x^5 + 52x^4 + 26x^3 + 30x^2 + 10x + 5"));
}

void TestPolynomialMultiplication_multiplybythis()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    poly1.multiply(poly2);
    assert(poly1 == polynomial("24x^5 + 52x^4 + 26x^3 + 30x^2 + 10x + 5"));
}

void TestPolynomialMultiplication_multiplybythis_operator()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    poly1 *= poly2;
    assert(poly1 == polynomial("24x^5 + 52x^4 + 26x^3 + 30x^2 + 10x + 5"));
}

void TestPolynomialMultiplication_function()
{
    polynomial poly1("6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2"), poly2("3x + 1 - x + 4x^2");
    assert(multiply(poly1, poly2) == polynomial("24x^5 + 52x^4 + 26x^3 + 30x^2 + 10x + 5"));
}
```

## Test Program

***main.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "polynomial.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::string choice;
    std::cout << "Select functionality (Enter 'add' for addition, 'sub' for subtraction,"
                 "'mul' for multiplication, and 'equ' to check equality between polynomials): ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cout << "Enter two polynomials:\n";
    polynomial poly1, poly2;
    std::cin >> poly1 >> poly2;

    if (choice == "add")
        std::cout << poly1 + poly2;
    else if (choice == "sub")
        std::cout << poly1 - poly2;
    else if (choice == "mul")
        std::cout << poly1 * poly2;
    else if (choice == "equ")
    {
        if (poly1 == poly2)
            std::cout << "Polynomials are equal";
        else
            std::cout << "Polynomials are not equal";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Invalid functionality";

    std::cin.get();
}
```

The `main()` function is just intended as a test, so it isn't optimal.
Let me know what you think!

Comment: How are these unit tests executed?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I call the test functions in a "unittests.cpp" file which is compiled separately.

Comment: How do you define a polynomial? Is the `x` an indeterminate (so `3x` != `3t`) or a variable (so `3x` and `3t` are the same function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Interface

The first thing I notice is that there is a lot of duplicated functions, because you provide a named function for each overloaded operator: `coefficient`, `add`, `plus`, `subtract`, `minus`, `multiply`, `times`, and `print`.  Some of them even have non-member versions.  This is not common practice in C++ as far as I can tell, so just eliminate them.

Returning a top-level `const` type is not helpful, because the cv-qualifications of non-class type prvalues are automatically stripped, and it is occasionally useful to perform a non-`const` operation on a class prvalue.  Marking a parameter as top-level `const` is also not helpful (especially in declarations), because they are stripped as part of the function signature and the point of passing by value is often just to get a modifiable object.

For small types like `std::size_t`, passing by value is more efficient than passing by const reference.

Binary operators are often overloaded as non-member functions, to minimize the burden of the class.

Some constructors should be marked as `explicit`, to prevent unwanted implicit conversion:

```
explicit polynomial(const std::string&);
explicit polynomial(const std::vector<long double>&);
```

Also, consider taking `std::string_view`s instead of `const std::string&`s.  The coefficient constructor should take the argument by value and move in, to enable move semantics:

```
explicit polynomial(std::vector<long double> coeff)
    : coefficients{std::move(coeff)}
{
    remove_trailing_zeros();
}
```

This function:

```
polynomial &operator=(const std::string&);
```

is unnecessary if the constructors are not explicit.  If they are, then this function probably shouldn't exist either because it's basically implicit conversion.

## Design

Right now, you represent zero polynomials as `[0]`, and treat their order as zero.  This is wrong, because the order of zero polynomials are usually left undefined or defined as negative infinity.  Rules like

$$
\deg(AB) = \deg(A) + \deg(B)
$$

will cease to work zero polynomials have order zero.  Consider representing zero polynomials as `[]` and throw an exception (or return a special type) in the `order` function.

Allowing write access to coefficients is not a good option, because this may break the no-trailing-zero class invariant.  The process of stripping trailing zeros can be extracted into a function:

```
private:
    void remove_trailing_zeros()
    {
        // ...
    }
```

As I mentioned in a comment, I'm not sure if the name of the variable should be considered part of the polynomial.  Conceptually, the variable should probably be specified as an output manipulator, like this:

```
std::cout << set_variable("x") << polynomial;
```

This can be implemented by adding facets to the locale of the stream (or by using the `std::ios_base::xalloc` mechanism if you want to be immune to locale changes).

Also consider making the class a template on the value type.

## Implementation

`(character >= '0' && character <= '9')` can be replaced by `std::isdigit(character)` (or `std::isdigit(character, std::locale::classic())` if someone called `std::setlocale`).

In my opinion, it is more convenient to implement modifying operations (`+=`, etc.) based on non-modifying operations (`+`, etc.) in this case, because we need to copy anyway:

```
friend polynomial operator+(const polynomial& lhs, const polynomial& rhs)
{
    const auto& [small, large] = std::minmax(lhs, rhs,
        [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
            return a.size() < b.size();
        }
    );

    auto result = large;
    std::transform(small.begin(), small.end(), result.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus{});
    return polynomial{std::move(result)}; // trailing zeros removed in constructor
}

polynomial& operator+=(const polynomial& other)
{
    return *this = *this + other;
}
```

Comment: I learned a lot from your review. Thank you for being thorough and concise. I do agree that there are too many functions for the same thing; I wanted to provide functions for every style. but come to think of it, it's unnecessary. Should I keep at least one alternative to operator overloads? (like add(poly1, poly2) for + operator overload)

Comment: @SalehShamloo If the function is identical to the operator, I'd say no, the operator is sufficient, so it isn't necessary to duplicate the same functionality. If there is no operator that naturally fits the operation, then go ahead and provide a named function - `order` is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

## `long double`

`long double` is a niche type with an inconsistent interpretation: sometimes it's a plain old 64bit `double`, sometimes 80bits extended-precision, sometimes (rarely) 128bit aka "quad". In the 80bit case, the actual storage requirement may be 10, 12 or 16 bytes. What you get depends on the targeted processor as well as the compiler and perhaps any special options given to the compiler. Such variations are not merely theoretical. For example, MSVC and GCC treat `long double` differently, even when they both target x86.

You can use it, but expect inconsistent results, even more than usual for floating point.

## Leading zeroes?

The "no leading zeroes" invariant is easy to break:

```
polynomial p = { "0x+1" };
```

Which gets printed back as `+ 1` instead of `1`.

You could argue that it's my fault for giving strange input intentionally, but it could be neater. Also, multiplication exacerbates the issue:

```
polynomial q = p * p;
```

Now `q` has two leading zeroes.

Leading zeroes can also be created from scratch, for example:

```
polynomial p = { "0.00000000000000001x+1" };
p = p * p;
p = p * p;
p = p * p;
p = p * p;
p = p * p;
p = p * p;
```

Due to the limited exponent range of whatever a `long double` turn out to be, eventually zeroes appear. I tried this with MSVC so `long double == double`, out of the 65 coefficients only the first 20 are non-zero. Of course, I'm using this strange example intentionally to cause the issue, it may not be a concern for your assignment.